# How to sync audio and video in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app i have to play  some video files.I also have to play audio files along with these video files.
It is working fine.But the problem is  audio and video file is not syncing properly.
Also when the the pause button is pressed the video is stop playing not the audio.Im playing the video in MPMOvieplayer controller.
How to solve this issue.Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using an `AVMutableComposition`. Try taking a look at [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_EditingAssets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH6-SW1) thing and if you need any help with it let me know. I would gladly help.